# Using goToSlide to open slider to relevant slide bxSlider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I need to be able to open a profile to the correct slide(dancer) using the bxSlider plugin. On page load the slider is hidden. I've set up data attributes on the thumbnails and classes on the slider li items so that they can be linked together. I just don't knowhow to use the slider api to replace the parameter in the goToSlide function. Code i currently have:

HTML

```
<div class="grid the-dancers">
    <div class="col col-2">
        <div class="member dancer" data-dancer="d-1">
            <h3>Name 1</h3>
            <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/images/team-member.jpg" alt="Elessha Drennan"></a>
            <a href="" class="info"><span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe082;"><span class="visually-hidden">Info</span></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
        <div class="member dancer" data-dancer="d-2">
            <h3>Name 2</h3>
            <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/images/team-member.jpg" alt="Elessha Drennan"></a>
            <a href="" class="info"><span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe082;"><span class="visually-hidden">Info</span></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
        <div class="member dancer" data-dancer="d-3">
            <h3>Name 3</h3>
            <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/images/team-member.jpg" alt="Elessha Drennan"></a>
            <a href="" class="info"><span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe082;"><span class="visually-hidden">Info</span></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dancer-profile-container">
    <div class="wrap content">
        <ul class="dance-slider">
          <li class="d-1">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="col col-3">
                    <h2>Name 1</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-9">
                    <div class="grid">
                        <div class="col col-3">
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/images/virtual-descent-intro.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-9">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="d-2">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="col col-3">
                    <h2>Name 2</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-9">
                    <div class="grid">
                        <div class="col col-3">
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/images/virtual-descent-intro.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-9">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="d-3">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="col col-3">
                    <h2>Name 3</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-9">
                    <div class="grid">
                        <div class="col col-3">
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/images/virtual-descent-intro.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-9">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="ds-close">Close</span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var danceSlider;

$(document).ready(function(){

danceSlider = $('.dance-slider').bxSlider({
    pager: false,
    onSliderLoad: function(){
        danceSlider.goToSlide(1);
        }
});

$('.member a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dancer-profile-container').fadeIn('fast');
    danceSlider.reloadSlider();
});
});
```

All this does at the moment is open up the slider to the second slide.

Comment: Check the answer below. See if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just posting a very basic answer. Modify it to suit your requirements.

Set your data-dancer to reflect the slide number

eg:

> ```
> <div class="member dancer" data-dancer="0">
> ```

```
 $('.member img').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //find the index of the item i.e 0th, or 1st or 2nd item in the list
   var index = $(this).parents('.member').attr('data-dancer');
   danceSlider.goToSlide(index);
 });
```

Here I made a jsfiddle too [SolutionFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vijeta/yxErC/)